# Spock check invocation using variable instead of literal

Tags: spock

I have a Spock test like this:

```groovy
class SomeSpec extends Specification {

    Map message

    String topicArn = "aws::fake-sns-topic"

    def 'test new message'() {
        when: 'A new message is received'
        message = [
                "ownerToken": null,
                "status": "NEW"
        ]
        def response = api.doHandleRequest(message)

        then: 'It is handled'
        1 * snsClient.publish(topicArn, JsonOutput.toJson([
                "ownerToken": null,
                "status": "NEW"
        ]))
    }
}
```

This works fine but I'd prefer to change the assertion to

```groovy
1 * snsClient.publish(topicArn, message)
```

to reduce duplication of the map literal. When I do I get the following error:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * snsClient.publish(topicArn, JsonOutput.toJson(message))   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * snsClient.publish('aws::fake-sns-topic', '{"ownerToken":null","status":"NEW"}')
One or more arguments(s) didn't match:
0: <matches>
1: argument == expected
   |        |  |
   |        |  null
   |        false
   {"ownerToken":null,"status":"NEW"}
```

Why is the second argument coming through as null when I use the message variable instead of a map literal? The first argument is a variable rather than a literal and it is coming through fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd prefer to change the assertion to
>
> ```groovy
> 1 * snsClient.publish(topicArn, message)
> ```

Well, it cannot work like that. As your posted test error implies, what you really want is

```groovy
1 * snsClient.publish(topicArn, JsonOutput.toJson(message))
```

which leads to the exception you see during the test.

The reason is that the interaction you are testing in the `then:` block must be prepared to be checked *before* the code in the `when:` block gets executed. But before that block `message` is `null`. So you want to assign the value in a `setup:` or `given:` (both are just aliases for each other) block:

```groovy
def 'new message gets published'() {
  given: 'a new message'
  message = [
    "ownerToken": null,
    "status"    : "NEW"
  ]

  when: 'the message is received'
  def response = api.doHandleRequest(message)

  then: 'it gets published'
  1 * snsClient.publish(topicArn, JsonOutput.toJson(message))
}
```

Now your test passes.